# Why await inside returned tuple make code slower?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have function:

```py
def foo(page_url: str):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(page_url) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                page = await response.text()
                return (page_url, page)
```

And it works correct, but i want to make await inside tuple:

```py
return(page_url, await response.text())
```

my programm immediately starts working **much slower**.

Why?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How did you time your code?

Comment: I suspect that the creation of the tuple is not interruptible in the same way the body of the `if` statement is between two statements. Do something else while waiting for the value to assign to `page`: OK. Do something else while waiting for the second element of the incomplete tuple to be available: not OK.

Comment: does doing `return page_url, await response.text()` still make it slow?

Comment: @chepner I don't think it's about the "interruptibility" of `BUILD_TUPLE`. `python -m dis` generates near-equivalent disassembly for both forms of the function aside from a single difference in a load_fast/store_fast order (sorry for just a screenshot): https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLCXa.png

Comment: I tested each version in a jupyter notebook and they both ran at the same speed for my PC.

Comment: I honestly think OP might have just measured this at a time where the remote server was responding much slower for some reason. (Also, you should share a ClientSession, not create a new one for every request.)

Comment: @AKX Possibly, but your screenshot seems to show more than just a reordering; there's an *additional* `STORE_FAST` and `LOAD_FAST` in one of them.

Comment: @chepner Well yes, there's an additional local variable that needs to be `STORE_FAST`ed.

Comment: @alec_djinn i use time.time() for check this.

Comment: @AKX why using one session is right way? When i try to do this i lost maybe 0.5 sec of speed

Comment: @chepner it might be true, thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce a drastic slowdown.

- I have `python -m http.server 8254 2>/dev/null` running, so there is no network interference here, and no background terminal being noisy either.

```
import asyncio
import sys

import aiohttp


async def getter_1(sess: aiohttp.ClientSession, page_url: str):
    async with sess.get(page_url) as response:
        if response.status == 200:
            page = await response.text()
            return (page_url, page)


async def getter_2(sess: aiohttp.ClientSession, page_url: str):
    async with sess.get(page_url) as response:
        if response.status == 200:
            return (page_url, await response.text())


def getter_test(getter):
    async def test():
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as sess:
            for x in range(3000):
                res = await getter(sess, 'http://127.0.0.1:8254/')
                assert res

    asyncio.run(test())


if sys.argv[1] == '1':
    getter_test(getter_1)
else:
    getter_test(getter_2)
```

Running this with [the `hyperfine` benchmark tool](https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine), I get a result

```
$ hyperfine 'python3 so73542988.py 1' 'python3 so73542988.py 2'
Benchmark 1: python3 so73542988.py 1
  Time (mean ± σ):      7.547 s ±  1.547 s    [User: 2.228 s, System: 0.298 s]
  Range (min … max):    6.417 s … 11.568 s    10 runs

Benchmark 2: python3 so73542988.py 2
  Time (mean ± σ):      7.863 s ±  0.524 s    [User: 2.217 s, System: 0.297 s]
  Range (min … max):    7.218 s …  8.831 s    10 runs

Summary
  'python3 so73542988.py 1' ran
    1.04 ± 0.22 times faster than 'python3 so73542988.py 2'
```

so nothing very drastic at all.

Comment: I have small difference between benchmarks too (maybe 0.2-0.4 sec) and i was interested why. Thank you!